# porting PyGST app to GStreamer1.0 + PyGI

Tags: python, gstreamer

I have a python audio player based on gstreamer and dbus http://sourceforge.net/p/autoradiobc/code/210/tree/trunk/autoradio/autoplayer/player_gstreamer1.py. It works with pygst and I want port it to gstreamer 1.
Following this how to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Novacut/GStreamer1.0 it's going to work but:

```
File "/home/pat1/svn/autoradio/autoradio/autoplayer/player.py", line 826, in position
except(Gst.QueryError):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/module.py", line 316, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._introspection_module, name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/module.py", line 135, in __getattr__
self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gst' object has no attribute 'QueryError'
```

it's in this part of code:

```
try:
  pos_int = self.player.query_position(Gst.Format.TIME, None)[0]
except(Gst.QueryError):
  logging.warning( "Gst.QueryError in query_position" )
  return None
```

bypassing this problem after I get :

```
if ret == Gst.State.CHANGE_FAILURE:
AttributeError: type object 'GstState' has no attribute 'CHANGE_FAILURE'
```

in this part of code:

```
ret = self.player.set_state(Gst.State.READY)
if ret == Gst.State.CHANGE_FAILURE:
  logging.error( "Unable to set the pipeline to the READY state.")
```

bypassing this problem too, I get:

```
File "/home/pat1/svn/autoradio/autoradio/autoplayer/player.py", line 659, in on_message_state_changed
(Gst.element_state_get_name(old_state),
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/module.py", line 316, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._introspection_module, name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/module.py", line 135, in __getattr__
self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gst' object has no attribute 'element_state_get_name'
```

in this part of code:

```
    logging.debug("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s. Pendig: %s"%
                 (Gst.element_state_get_name(old_state),
                  Gst.element_state_get_name (new_state),
                  Gst.element_state_get_name (pending_state)))
```

commenting out element_state_get_name the player is going to work ....

How I can migrate to gstreamer 1 the full code without bypass the broken code ?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find solution to the first problem about QueryError

but :

```
if ret == Gst.State.CHANGE_FAILURE:
```

become:

```
if ret == Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE:
```

and:

```
Gst.element_state_get_name(old_state)
```

become:

```
Gst.Element.state_get_name(old_state)
```

and:

```
      self.player.set_new_stream_time(0L)
```

become:

```
      self.player.set_start_time(0L)
```

and:

```
     event = Gst.event_new_seek(1.0, Gst.Format.TIME,
             Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH|Gst.SeekFlags.ACCURATE,
             Gst.SEEK_TYPE_SET, tnano, Gst.SEEK_TYPE_NONE, 0)
```

become:

```
     event = Gst.Event.new_seek(1.0, Gst.Format.TIME,
             Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH|Gst.SeekFlags.ACCURATE,
             Gst.SeekType.SET, tnano, Gst.SeekType.NONE, 0)
```

and:

```
    pos_int = self.player.query_duration(Gst.Format.TIME, None)[0]
```

become:

```
    pos_int = self.player.query_duration(Gst.Format.TIME)[1]
```